# Django Error (unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'NoneType')

Tags: python, django, database, view

I'm facing an issue of **unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'NoneType'**

actually I want to sum two different database column value in specific date range and one column has no value in this specific date range and that's why I'm facing that issue can anyone one help me

One more thing help me to solve this in simple ways because I have many more arguments like that and if I use condition to make that value to zero that will be difficult for me

the date range(`modified6`, `modified5`) is correct, if it contain a value, it display the number

```
cell = Celldetail.objects.filter(DatePur__range=[modified6, modified5]).aggregate(Sum('Cell_price'))['Cell_price__sum']
bms = BMSdetail.objects.filter(DatePur__range=[modified6, modified5]).aggregate(Sum('BMS_price'))['BMS_price__sum']

month6price : cell + bms,
```

the error is on bms variable because bms has no number in this date range

Comment: Instead of ‘['BMS_price__sum']’ use ‘.get('BMS_price__sum', 0)’ to return zero instead of None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use `float(VarName or 0)` to convert your value to 0 if NoneTpye found, for example I use below method to solve my problem

```
month6price : float(cell or 0) + float(bms or 0),
```